# In R, how do I create a spatial grid using Leaflet and SF that is color coded based on some variable

Tags: r, leaflet

I am working with some state in the United States. I have latitude and longitude data (comprising two different columns) and I have a third column, let's call it L1, containing a value from 1-10. I want to create a grid of squares over the state and then fill in the grid with a color scale whereby the color is determined by the average value of L1 of all geographic points that fall into that square on the grid.

After running the following code below, I got an error message saying "Error in to_ring.default(x) :
Don't know how to get polygon data from object of class XY,POINT,sfg" which confuses me because I thought I was passing in grid coordinates, with each grid being a polygon. But apparently I am passing in points not polygons. Please help.

```
# Create a simple feature object from your data
points <- st_as_sf(data, coords = c("Long", "Lat"), crs = 4326)

# Create a grid over the bounding box of your points
bb <- st_bbox(points)
grid <- st_make_grid(st_as_sfc(bb), cellsize = 0.1)
grid <- st_sf(grid, crs = st_crs(points))

# Calculate the average of L1 for each grid cell
grid$L1 <- aggregate(points["L1"], grid, function(x) mean(as.numeric(x), na.rm = TRUE))$L1

grid_sp <- as(grid, "Spatial")

# Create a color palette function
pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "viridis", domain = grid$L1)

# Create a map widget by calling leaflet()
m <- leaflet() %>%
  # Add a Tiles layer to the map
  addTiles() %>%
  # Add state boundaries to the map
  addPolygons(data = us_map, weight = 1, color = "#444444", fill = NA) %>%
  # Add the grid layer to the map
  addPolygons(data = grid, fillColor = ~pal(L1), fillOpacity = 0.8, 
              color = "#BDBDC3", weight = 1) %>%
  # Add a legend
  addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~L1, opacity = 0.8, title = "Average L1")

# Print the map
m
```

Comment: would you be open to a solution that involves the `terra::` package as well?

Comment: @sean Yes please, Sean.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this with sf example shapes ( `read_sf(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))` ) and randomly sampled points, `st_make_grid()` generates polygons by default and `aggregate()` works fine for me. There is an issue with formula notation in `addLegend()`, but that can't produce the included error.  Where exactly did this error occur?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can accomplish what you are after by using the `terra::rasterize()` function more easily than using the `sf::st_make_grid()` .  Note, that using the `terra::` method, you will be creating a raster grid rather than a network of vector polygons, so your second call to `leaflet::addPolygons()` should really be `leaflet::addRasterImage()`. The `sf::st_make_grid()` call requires the `what="polygons"` argument to create a polygon. I imagine this is the source of the error you have been receiving.  Below is a reproducible example using the `terra::rasterize()` workflow.  In it, I first take a vector version of the us state of Oregon and create a  blank raster to fit its bounding box and at my desired resolution. Then I create a random network of points and randomly assign them an L1 value from 1 to 10.  Finally I use the `terra::rasterize()` function to aggregate the points into the raster cells, taking the average value of L1 for all points within each raster cell.  I tweaked your call to `leaflet::` to accommodate the raster with the `addRasterImage()` function.  Hope this is what you are after.

```
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(leaflet)
library(spData)

data("us_states")

##Get a simple feature of the US State of Oregon## 
oregon<-st_transform(us_states[us_states$NAME=="Oregon",], crs=4326)#transformed to WGS84, EPSG:4326

##Creating points within the State##
pts<-st_as_sf(st_sample(oregon, 50000, type="random"))
pts[,"L1"]<-sample(1:10, 50000, replace=TRUE)

##Create blank raster to populate##
OR_rast<-rast(extent=ext(oregon), ncols=500, nrows=200, crs="EPSG:4326")

#Rasterizing points' L1 values using the terra::rasterize() function##
L1_rast<-rasterize(x=pts, y=OR_rast, field="L1", fun="mean")

# Create a color palette function
pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "viridis", domain = 1:10)

# Create a map widget by calling leaflet()
m <- leaflet() %>%
  # Add a Tiles layer to the map
  addTiles() %>%
  # Add state boundaries to the map
  addPolygons(data = oregon, weight = 1, color = "#444444", fill = NA) %>%
  # Add the grid layer to the map
  addRasterImage(x = L1_rast, colors=pal, opacity = 0.8) %>%
  # Add a legend
  addLegend(pal = pal, values = 1:10, opacity = 0.8, title = "Average L1")

# Print the map
m
```